# Where on earth is this church which looks like a confused chicken?

Tags: where-on-earth, architecture, identify-this, religion

This picture has been circulating on twitter and in the office.  But it doesn't say where it is. Can anyone provide the church's location?

[image: Confused chicken or church]

Comment: Free hint: http://images.google.com provides the option to search by uploaded photo or url. (See camera-icon)

Comment: My understanding is that it's an owl not a chicken, and when you walk around the building the owl eyes follow you as an owl can turn its head 360 degrees...maybe someone can research this. It's located in Madeira Beach Florida.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the [Church By The Sea in Tampa Bay, Florida](http://metro.co.uk/2013/03/04/from-chicken-church-to-house-that-looks-like-hitler-top-5-buildings-that-look-like-other-things-3525865/).

> Visitors have flocked to the Church By The Sea in Tampa Bay, Florida after word spread of its resemblance to a character from hit game Angry Birds. While visitors can clearly make out the bird’s eyes, beak and wings, the church’s resemblance to a  feathered animal is purely coincidental.

This is a satellite view from [Google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Church+By+The+Sea+in+Tampa+Bay,+Florida.&hl=en&ll=27.793692,-82.790525&spn=0.002389,0.003455&sll=21.556645,39.193853&sspn=0.909384,1.768799&t=h&hq=Church+By+The+Sea&hnear=Tampa+Bay&z=19). 
[The church's official website](http://www.churchbythesea.com/).

Answer (score 5):

This is Church By the Sea - around the corner from my childhood home, Madeira Beach, Florida. It faces the Gulf of Mexico (not Tampa Bay) and reminds me of Perry the Platypus.

Comment: Thanks, Local knowledge is always better than just internet information.

Comment: Er, zooming in on google it seems to  technically face SE towards Tampa Bay ;) https://www.google.com/maps/place/Church+by+the+Sea/@27.7568777,-82.7916202,2882a,35y,341.1h,54.11t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xcc3ba9515d7a6126!8m2!3d27.793705!4d-82.7906819

Comment: @MarkMayo:  The body of water southeast of the church is [Boca Ciega Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boca_Ciega_Bay).  Tampa Bay is the body of water about 15 km east, directly to the east of Saint Petersburg.